# all list values same

Tags: python, list

In Python, is the a simple way to test that all values in a list are equal to one another?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Many ways come to mind. <del>You could turn it in a `set` (which filters out duplicates) and check for length of one</del>Edit: As another poster noted, this only works with hashable types; I revoke the suggestion as it has worse performance *and* is less general.

You could use a generator expression: `all(items[0] == item for item in items)`, which would short-circuit (i.e. return false as soon as the predicate fails for an item instead of going on).

Comment: +1 Using list comprehensions is recommended over map().

Comment: @Artanis: It's not a list comprehension - that's why it's superior to the `set` solution ;)

Comment: Thanks! this is simple and sweet!

Comment: ah, I missed that it lacked the brackets. Should be a generator then.

Comment: i also thought it was a list comprehension, what is it called? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> len(set(a))
1
```

Note that this method assumes that each element in your list can be placed into a set. Some types, such as the mutable types, cannot be placed into a set.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> l = [1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> all(map(lambda x: x == l[0], l))
True
```

Comment: Note that this iterates through the while list unconditionally (there are several equally simple solutions that don't).

Comment: `map` is an iterator in Python 3, so `all` won't iterate past the first unequal value. Or in Python 2, use `functools.imap`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `set` as pointed out by Greg Hewgill is a great solution. Here's another one that's more lazy, so if one pair of the elements are not equal, the rest will not be compared. This might be slower than the `set` solution when comparing all items, but didn't benchmark it.

```
l = [1, 1, 1]
all(l[i] == l[i+1] for i in range(len(l)-1))
```

Note the special case `all([]) == True`.

Comment: This will compare each item with the next one (and raise an out of range error for odd-length inputs).

Comment: @delnan: Yes it might be better to just take the first element (if there's one) and compare it to all others. But what do you mean by odd-length input?

Comment: A `l` for which `n = len(l)` is odd that doesn't terminate erlier will try to access `l[n-1+1] = l[n]`, which is out of range.

Comment: @delnan: Isn't that exactly what the example in my answer shows? I'm using `range(len(l)-1)`, i.e. the range will go from 0 to `len(l)-2`, so I don't think your objection is correct?!

Comment: Yes, nevermind (it's incorrect, but it won't crash).